# submitting form through ajax doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, internet-explorer-8

When I submit the form using ajax in Internet Explorer, instead of submitting the form, all the variables that are being sent appear in the address bar. Any ideas how to fix this?

Here's what appears in the address bar: `mypage/home?v1=name&0v=0&v2=&v3=`

Here's the code:

```
$(".submitF").live(
    "submit", function () {
        var fcontent = $(this).serialize();
        var divs = $(this).attr("data-div");
        divs = divs.split(",");
        $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "core/ajax.php",
                data: "ajax=ajax&divs=" + divs + fcontent,
                beforeSend: function () {
                    centerWin("loading");
                },
                complete: function () {
                    $("#loading").hide("fast");
                },
                success: function (html) {
                    $("#mainWin").html(html).addClass(newClass);
                });
            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'd want your:

```
      var divs = $(this).attr("data-div");       
      divs = divs.split(",");
```

Inside the ajax method call, move that outside and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Plain and simple - you cannot use `.live(...)` with `submit`

Comment: Turns out that you can after all ... with the latest JQuery :)